# Rails: Include Javascript_include_tag outside default folders

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, templates, directory

I have a template that I'm trying to include on my Rails Aplication.
This template has it's own structure that I don't want to mess with.
Lets call this template "material".

I've put all the files under `my vendor/assets` folder, so that I have this structure:

```
railsApp/vendor/assets/material/material
```

Inside this last "material" folder, I have the folders with my JS and CSS. This way I've created a file "material.js" that does the includes:

```
//= require material/js/jquery-2.1.1
//= require material/js/functions
//= require material/js/bootstrap
```

so that I can call the js that I want.

Here is my problem:
How can I call this material.js from my `application.html.erb` ?

```
<%= javascript_include_tag '/vendor/assets/material/material/material', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Does not work...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a new js file, let's say `material.js`. In `app/assets/javascripts/material.js`:

`//= require material/material`

Then in your `config/application.rb`, you need to add:

`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'material')`.

You would also need to add `material.js` to the pre-compile list. In `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( material.js )`.

And then in your view, you can reference material:

`javascript_include_tag 'material'`